# Couldn't add New Bridge NAT Rule - ip matchers valid only for ip ethernet protocol

Tags: port-forwarding, mikrotik, routeros

I am following [this tutorial](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Initial_Configuration#Port_forwarding) to set up port forwarding. However, when I attempt to apply my rule, I get the above error message.

Here is the rule that I am trying to add: [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNqlf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to specify the MAC Protocol as "800 (ip)"